# C++ string comparison help me out

Tags: c++

```
bool checkPalindrome(string inputString) {
int h = inputString.length();
string reverse;
char b;
for (int i = 0; i <= inputString.length(); i++)
{

     b = inputString[i];
     reverse.push_back(b);
     h--;
}
cout << reverse;
if (reverse == inputString)
{
   
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

}

iam a rookie and while expermenting code stuck in one place,

[1] passed value "a" to inputString so  both reverse and inputString carry same value but nvr go inside loop

[2] changed     b = inputString[i];    to b = inputString[h];  after that iam not able to pushback the value

help me guys

Answer (score 3):

One problem is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= inputString.length(); i++)
```

... the condition-check should be comparing with `<`, not `<=`.  To understand why, consider the string-accesses inside the for-loop with `<=` when inputString="ABC", for which `inputString.length()` will return 3:

```
inputString[0] = 'A';
inputString[1] = 'B';
inputString[2] = 'C';
inputString[3] = ???   // invalid index!  Bad!
```

The same problem occurs if you try to use `h`:

```
 int h = inputString.length();   // for "ABC", h=3
 [...]

 b = inputString[h];    // inputString[3] is out of bounds!  Bad!
 reverse.push_back(b);
 h--;                   // decrement to 2 happens too late
```

... so to do it that way, you would want to decrement `h` *before* using it to index into the string, i.e.:

```
 int h = inputString.length();   // for "ABC", h=3
 [...]

 h--;                   // decrement first
 b = inputString[h];    // inputString[2] = "C", OK
 reverse.push_back(b);
```

Comment: Technically `inputString[inputString.length()] ` is not invalid index, points at terminating zero, and `data() ` required to include it as well  (unlike in C++98) so technically referring to is wrong only because it provides wrong starting point for comparison

Answer (score 1):

@Jeremy's answer has explained what you stuck in. I just show you a quicker algorithm to solve this problem. Actually you just need to compare left side and right side of input string, if they are same, return true, if not, return false.

```
bool checkPalindrome(string inputString) {
    int h = inputString.length();
    for(int i=0;i<h/2;i++){
        if (inputString[i]!=inputString[h-i-1]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: its not about algoritham , i already solved in different method i want to know the reason of my mistake